# Understanding SQL insert query referencing other tables

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I'll start with explaining my setup in full.
I'm running opencart, and there are many instances where I would like to assign a manufacturer to an entire category. Rather than going in and assigning a manufacturer to each individual product I know enough that this can be done with one SQL query. I'm hoping this answer and example will offer me a better understanding in the future when I need to do a mass update

I have a table oc_product with the following column headings

> product_id     model   sku     upc     ean     jan     isbn    mpn     location    quantity    stock_status_id     image   manufacturer_id     shipping    price   points  tax_class_id    date_available

I then have a table called oc_product_to_category with the following column headings

> product_id     category_id

I would like to assign a manufacturer id in oc_products based upon which category the products are in reference to oc_product_to_category.

For example... If I want all products with category_id equal to "9" with a manufacturer id of "32"

Thank you to anyone that can provide me a little guidance.

Comment: How are you associating manufacturer_id to category_id?

Comment: In pseudo i would like to update manufacturer ID in oc_product where category_id in oc_product_to_category is equal to a particular category id. Is that not possible? Am I missing a required table somewhere? Because there is no manufacturer_to_category table.

Comment: @user2733862 see my suggested answer. Doesn't it work for you?

Comment: it worked!!! Thank you. I'll be able to reference this for multiple future edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE oc_product, oc_product_to_category
SET oc_product.manufacturer_id = 32
WHERE
    oc_product.product_id = oc_product_to_category.product_id AND
    oc_product_to_category.category_id = 9
```

EDIT following follow-up request:

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO oc_product_filter(product_id, filter_id)
    SELECT oc_product_to_category.product_id, 42
    FROM oc_product_to_category
    WHERE oc_product_to_category.category_id = 9
```

Comment: one follow up question. If I have a table that is oc_product_filter with colums
> product_id filter_id
But I need to create a new entry in this table to make all products with a category id of 9 to a certain filter_id

Having to insert and not update is whats throwing me off.

Comment: @user2733862 I updated the answer to include a query for inserting new rows into oc_product_filter...

Comment: this query will not apply a filter_id will it? It will only insert the product id into oc_product_filter?

Comment: filter id should be a completely new integer based upon which category the product is located in.

Comment: should I just add. set oc_product_filter.filter_id = 2 at the end?